# How to hide a div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I want to hide a HTML `<div>`, I use the following JavaScript code:

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
div.style.visibility = "hidden";
div.style.display = "none";
```

What is the equivalent of that code in jQuery?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

```
$('#myDiv').hide();
```

or

```
$('#myDiv').slideUp();
```

or

```
$('#myDiv').fadeOut();
```

Comment: That's actually all three the same `display:none` with just three different animation effect. The correct answer is by @honk31 `.css("visibility", "hidden")` and there is a purpose! The `visiblity:hidden` unlike `display:none` keeps using space while `display:none` will behave like it never existing there.

Comment: @Developer While an interesting and potentially useful point, I see absolutely nothing indicating your solution was the desired effect. To the contrary, it would seem the OP found it to answer their question quite well. For my purposes as well, continuing to take up the space would actually be pretty undesirable. Don't be arrogant.

Comment: Like we used to say before RTFM. In the initial post, a person asks what is the difference between visibility = "hidden" and display = "none", did he ever ask how to make hiding animation? Stay to the topic!

Answer (score 38):

```
$("#myDiv").hide();
```

will set the css display to none.
if you need to set visibility to hidden as well, could do this via

```
$("#myDiv").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

or combine both in a chain

```
$("#myDiv").hide().css("visibility", "hidden");
```

or write everything with one css() function

```
$("#myDiv").css({
  display: "none",
  visibility: "hidden"
});
```

Comment: This answer should be selected as a correct, I have no idea why people voted for completely wrong answer!

Comment: To make it visible, use `visible` instead of `hidden`.

Answer (score 29):

Easy:

```
$('#myDiv').hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 20):

If you want the element to keep its space then you need to use,

```
$('#myDiv').css('visibility','hidden')
```

If you dont want the element to retain its space, then you can use,

```
$('#myDiv').css('display','none')
```

or simply,

```
$('#myDiv').hide();
```

Answer (score 7):

`$("myDiv").hide();` and `$("myDiv").show();` does not work in Internet Explorer that well.

The way I got around this was to get the html content of  `myDiv` using `.html()`.

I then wrote it to a newly created DIV. I then appended the DIV to the body and appended the content of the variable `Content` to the `HiddenField` then read that contents from the newly created div when I wanted to show the DIV.

After I used the `.remove()` method to get rid of the DIV that was temporarily holding my DIVs html.

```
var Content = $('myDiv').html(); 
        $('myDiv').empty();
        var hiddenField = $("<input type='hidden' id='myDiv2'>");
        $('body').append(hiddenField);
        HiddenField.val(Content);
```

and then when I wanted to SHOW the content again.

```
        var Content = $('myDiv');
        Content.html($('#myDiv2').val());
        $('#myDiv2').remove();
```

This was more reliable that the `.hide()` & `.show()` methods.

Answer (score 6):

`$('#myDiv').hide()` will hide the div...

Answer (score 2):

`$('#myDiv').hide();` hide function is used to edit content and show function is used to show again.

For more please click on [this link](https://youtu.be/5dcLcVpP_ts).