# jQuery - hide div when input length is less than 3 chafacters

Tags: jquery

I would like to hide a div when the input length is less than 3 characters long.

**Here is my code:**

```
<div id="Container" class="content">
<input type="text" name="search" class="search" id="searchid" placeholder="Wyszukaj..." /><br /> 
<div id="result"></div>
</div>

<script>
$('input[name=search]').change(function()
{
      if( $(this).val().length < 3 ) {
           jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
      }
});
</script>
```

**IMPORTANT:** That should work when user is changing this input.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this not working or what is the issue here?

Comment: How does it fail?  Never changes?  Actually throws an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `.keyup()` event to capture *while* the user is changing the input value. `change()` will only fire when the input loses focus.

```js
$('input[name="search"]').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length < 3) {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input name="search" placeholder="Hello" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
$('#result').hide();
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375449/how-to-hide-a-div-with-jquery

Comment: Doesn't work too. Maybe change() is valid function in this case?