# DOM.style.display is not working as intended. Can't hide div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I'm trying to implement a search bar using Fuse.js.

```
            const fuse = new Fuse(rows, searchOptions);
            let searchResults = fuse.search(e);

            console.log(searchResults);

            if (searchResults.length > 0) {
                rows.forEach(function (item, index) {
                    item.style.display = "none";
                    searchResults.forEach(function (searchHit, hitIndex) {
                        if (searchHit.item == item)
                            item.style.display = "flex";
                    });
                });
            }
```

When the code is run, nothing visible happens.
If I replace item.style.display with item.style.color and try to change the color, it identifies the right cards and colors them correctly.

I've tried adding "!important", but the result stays the same. I've also tried $(item).hide() in a futile attempt.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375449/how-to-hide-a-div-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working! Thank you!

I'm still not sure what was wrong, but hiding the div using the Bootstrap "d-none" class worked.

```
if (searchResults.length > 0) {
    rows.forEach(function(item){
        item.classList.remove("d-flex");
        item.classList.add("d-none");
        searchResults.forEach(function (searchHit){
            if(searchHit.item == item){
                item.classList.remove("d-none");
                item.classList.add("d-flex");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good. I think that your problem might be with the `if` statement. Try added an `else` afterwards because your code in the `if` statement will only run on that condition. Try adding an `alert()`  for an test. When my code doesn't run as expected I have three things that I do:

1. I go through my code and check for syntax errors.
2. I check the console to see if there are any errors that I could have missed.
3. I add `console.log(1)` or `alert(1)` after certain parts of my code to see if that code even gets run.

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest the following:

```
if (searchResults.length) {
  rows.forEach(function (item) {
    if (searchResult.indexOf(item.textContent) >= 0) {
      item.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
      item.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}
```

This will iterate each row and see if the `item` is in the `searchResults` array. This assumes that `item` is a Element that would be in the Array.

Based on your code, I suspect that `rows` are some collection of HTML Elements. You will want to get the `textContent` of that element when compring it to the `searchResults` assuming they are Strings.